# Usage of "to" in the mentioned sentence

Tags: grammar, infinitives

The first sentence on this page: https://www.wired.com/2015/02/powerspy-phone-tracking/ says `SMARTPHONE USERS MIGHT balk at letting a random app like Candy Crush or Shazam track their every move via GPS.`, now I wonder why there is no `to` before the word `track`, e.g.: `SMARTPHONE USERS MIGHT balk at letting a random app like Candy Crush or Shazam to track their every move via GPS.` Could you someone please clarify if adding `to` before the word `track` is still correct English? If that is wrong, could someone help me understand why?

Thanks!

Comment: In the example you cite, "to" is incorrect for the reasons stated in the answer you have been given.

Comment: @Hi ohwilleke, thanks for the answer. Could you please clarify why it is wrong? Also, about `in the answer you have been given`, I haven't given an answer actually :)

Comment: I mean the answer from Sahil Agarwal who accurately notes that the word "to" is not used for subjects but is used for objects.

Comment: By the way @ohwilleke, I also commented on Sahil Agarwal's answer, could you also please take a look? Thanks!

Comment: @ohwilleke, by the way, you mentioned `"to" is not used for subjects but is used for objects`, does that mean that the sentence has two subjects? `SMARTPHONE USERS` and `random app like Candy Crush or Shazam`?

Comment: Hmmm.. . . you almost need to diagram the sentence. The primary verb is "might balk" for which the subject is "Smartphone Users", but there is a secondary verb "track" for which the subject is "a random app" and the object is "their every move", with "like Candy Crush or Shazam" clarifying the meaning of "a random app" and "via GPS" modifying  the secondary verb "track". "at letting" is operating more like a conjunction of connecting phrase than like a gerund phrase. I'm not used to describing such a complex sentence with formal terminology, and may lack the right terminology for some parts.

Answer (score 1):

Track is a verb.

I track his activity. 
Spiderman tracked the villain. 
Apps track location.

Using to with track is possible.

I love to track his activity.
Apps to track location.

In "Apps track location", app is the doer. It means "apps are tracking location".

In "Apps to track location" app is an object. It means "app is being used to track location".

Same difference in "I track his activity" and "I love to track his activity".

Comment: Hi @Sahil, thanks for your answer. I have a question. Am I right that `letting a random app like Candy Crush or Shazam track their every move via GPS` is a gerund phrase? If so, could you please clarify what parts of speech `letting` and `track` are? Thanks!